# Php Session Variable Error

Tags: php, html, variables, session

Hey i got some problem with session and invalid variable :O 
IMO i maybe think it can be about PHP_SELF or the variable $nombreentre
But i will let u check that:)
Thx

```
<?php 
    $formulaire = '<FORM method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER[\"PHP_SELF\"]; ?>">
    <p>
    <label>Entrez un nombre de 0 a 100 :</label> <input name="nombre" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value ="Valider !"/>
    </p>
    </form>' ;

    if(isset($_POST['nombre']))
    {
    $nombreentre = htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['nombre']));}

if (empty($_SESSION['nombremystere']))
{
    $_SESSION['nombremystere'] = mt_rand(0, 100);
    echo $formulaire;
}
else
{
        if ($_SESSION['nombremystere'] > $nombreentre)
        {
            echo 'C\'est plus !';
            echo $formulaire;
        }
        elseif ($_SESSION['nombremystere'] < $nombreentre)
        {
            echo 'C\'est moins !';
            echo $formulaire;
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Bravo, vous avez trouve le nombre mystere !';
            session_destroy();
        }
}    
?>
```

Comment: Wow here come the downvotes. You ask questions after testing and showing that you can debug. Saying you think it might be something but you will let us debug it.... sorry man but probably won't get any help.

Comment: i try to find it about 4hour, i just dont know what to do, the answer can be between these hint but i didnt find anywhere an idea of what i could write instead .. :(

Comment: You could start by displaying what error you are getting.

Comment: Undefined variable: nombreentre

Comment: Makes sense because you are creating that variable inside the if(isset($_POST['nombre']) {} IF clause. That means it isn't a created variable in the rest of the script unless that IF evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: Thx Alot, it help me fix this, i got an other problem , but it was my file name, i rename it to delete space and such thing, thanks alot and next time i will try to be more clear on my message, its my first time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

We are just shifting the closing } of the first IF.

```
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
    $nombreentre = htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['nombre']));

    if (empty($_SESSION['nombremystere']))
    {
        $_SESSION['nombremystere'] = mt_rand(0, 100);
        echo $formulaire;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($_SESSION['nombremystere'] > $nombreentre)
        {
            echo 'C\'est plus !';
            echo $formulaire;
        }
        elseif ($_SESSION['nombremystere'] < $nombreentre)
        {
            echo 'C\'est moins !';
            echo $formulaire;
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Bravo, vous avez trouve le nombre mystere !';
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `isset($_POST['nombre'])` evaluates to true and `$_SESSION['nombremystere']` is not set, you will get an undefined index notice - you also need to check it with `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code, but the undefined variable error occurs when `isset($_POST['nombre'])` and `empty($_SESSION['nombremystere'])` both return false.

You need to refine your logic - probably to something more along these lines:

```
// we can only check for a win if we have an answer *and* the user has made a guess
if(isset($_SESSION['nombremystere']) && isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
    $nombreentre = htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['nombre']));
    if ($_SESSION['nombremystere'] > $nombreentre) {
        echo 'C\'est plus !';
        echo $formulaire;
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['nombremystere'] < $nombreentre) {
        echo 'C\'est moins !';
        echo $formulaire;
    }
    else {
        echo 'Bravo, vous avez trouve le nombre mystere !';
        session_destroy();
    }
}

// either the user hasn't submitted a guess, or we haven't generated a random number for them to guess
else {
    $_SESSION['nombremystere'] = mt_rand(0, 100);
    echo '<form method="post" action="' . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . '">
    <p>
    <label>Entrez un nombre de 0 a 100 :</label> <input name="nombre" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value ="Valider !"/>
    </p>
    </form>';
}
```